# How can I redirect rsync output to a directory with date and time stamp?

Tags: rsync

I want to redirect the output of `rsync` to a particular directory with the date and time stamp.

Example: `rsync -r source-dir dest-dir/current-date-time`

Is there any way the "current-date-time" folder can be created automatically?
My main aim is to run the `rsync` command in a cron job and I want the output to be stored in multiple directories (with the date and time) under destination.

Is that possible in single `rsync` command?

I do understand `-t` preserves modification time so I may use 
`rsync -avH -t <source> <dest>` but is the directory creation (with date and time) possible at the destination?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, there is no possibility to create the directory from within the rsync command.

But what about writing a simple bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
myDate="$(date +%F)"
mkdir -p "dest-dir/$myDate"
rsync -r source-dir dest-dir/"$myDate"
exit 0
```

Comment: The `exit 0` at the end would mask any errors that `rsync` may produce in case this script is used in a conditional statement or similar context.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda for the edit and the comment on `exit 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command:

```
rsync -avH <source> <dest>/"$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')"/
```

Command substitution (`$(...)`) is used to create the name for a new directory under `<dest>` as the current date + time.

Note that the above command will create the `<source>` directory under `<dest>/<current_date-time>/`. If you want to just copy the *content* of `<source>`, use:

```
rsync -avH <source>/ <dest>/"$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')"/
```

(relevant is the `/` after `<source>`).

As mentioned in [another answer you have](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504932/315749), with some `date` implementations (e.g. [GNU `date`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#date-invocation)), the `%F` format specifier can be used for "date in ISO format", thus abbreviating `'%Y-%m-%d'`. Note that `%F` is not specified in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) for the `date` utility (but many `date` implementations are able to use this format string as they depend on [`strftime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html), which will support it).

Comment: It is true that `%F` is not in POSIX for the `date` utility, it is however defined for the `strftime()` C function, on which most `date` implementations rely.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks! I think this is really useful, feel free to edit my answer (implementation details are usually beyond my knowledge).